# How to validate only present fields with autoform?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Ok so I have a following situation. I have a Links collection that has a title and a URL. I'm using meteor-autoform to allow user to enter them. Now all links must have a title and a URL so I added following schema:

```
Links.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  href: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url,
    label: "Link"

  }
}));
```

However user only enters a href value for the link in front end, and title is automatically generated in the back end. Now if I use autoform to only submit the title nothing get's submitted because validations fail on the front-end (the title is missing). When I set title to optional - everything works, but I want to have that constraint on the database.

Can I tell Meteor to only validate some fields on front-end?

Comment: did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes You need to use the `AutoForm.getFieldValue('someField', 'someId');`

Autoforms Have a Section on the README named [Fine Tunnel Validation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#fine-tuning-validation)

also you can use the [AutoForm.getFieldValue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/api.md#autoformgetformvaluesformidclient)

Another Way to validate if the Form is valid is like this.

```
AutoForm.getValidationContext(Links).isValid()
```

The isValid is not on docs but Check [this Github Issue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/872)